# How to constrain a QSpinBox to valid values

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

Suppose I want a `QSpinBox` to have valid values from 0 to 10 with a step of 2 (i.e., 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10).
I can set the `QSpinBox` to have minimum of 0 and maximum of 10, with a singleStep of 2. If users click the up/down arrows, it works well. However, if user type in an odd number (say 3), the spinbox still think it is valid and accepts it. 
Whatelse should I do so that my QSpinBox will not allow odd numbers in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To correct this problem you can implement the valueChanged signal, verify if the value is correct, if it is not modicas nothing, in contrast if not, you place the previous value.

**Example:**

```
import sys

from PyQt4.QtCore import pyqtSignal
from PyQt4.QtGui import QApplication, QSpinBox


class SpinBox(QSpinBox):
    # Replaces the valueChanged signal
    newValueChanged = pyqtSignal(int)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(SpinBox, self).__init__(parent=parent)

        self.valueChanged.connect(self.onValueChanged)
        self.before_value = self.value()
        self.newValueChanged.connect(self.slot)

    def onValueChanged(self, i):
        if not self.isValid(i):
            self.setValue(self.before_value)
        else:
            self.newValueChanged.emit(i)
            self.before_value = i

    def isValid(self, value):
        if (self.minimum() - value % self.singleStep()) == 0:
            return True
        return False

    def slot(self, value):
        print(value)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = SpinBox()
    w.setMinimum(0)
    w.setMaximum(10)
    w.setSingleStep(2)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Works like a charm. With little modification, I can now set the value to it's closest valid value instead of keeping the previous value. Thanks.

Comment: After careful testing, I found some remaining issue in the current implementation. Suppose user type in a non-valid value of 3. With current implementation, the SpinBox.valueChanged signal is still emitted with a non-valid value of 3. How do I adress this?

Comment: @Hongzheng
Of course the signal is emitted, but the code corrects the value.

Comment: I would like the SpinBox widget to emit the signal with valid values because other parts of my program will responds to this and will cause issue if a non-valid value is emiited.

Comment: @Hongzheng 
What you should do is create a new signal, and you would connect to that signal, would you like it?

Comment: Emitting a new signal should work for me if no better solution is available.